# Change/Add Flash Trusted Location folder from .net client app?

Tags: .net, flash, actionscript-3

I have a .net client app that needs to play some content (images, movies, swf files etc) on the client machine. What it does is download the content from a server to the HDD in a folder, and play it. BUT: the SWF file has a need to read RSS from the web, and what i need is the folder where the app content is kept to be added in Trusted Locations (what you regulary do when right click .swf file, go to Global Settings > Advanced tab, and Trusted locations.. button, and specify a folder.

Now, i have searched the web, and there is a place where this is saved: :\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys\settings.sol, however, i don't know if this is changeable from another app : eg. when my .net app is installed or started, that it adds the folder to trusted locations, so that the SWF would be able to play RSS from web.

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the answer, what you have to do is to create new folder in C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash (name the folder FlashPlayerTrust). Then inside, put a new .cfg file with the trusted folder, path to the SWF, or swf directly:
C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\FlashPlayerTrust\anyNameHere.cfg. The contents of the .cfg is this:
C:\PathToSWF
or
C:\Path\File.swf 
etc.

More detailed explanation you can find here: http://muratsalma.com/en/blog/flashplayer-security-and-bypassing-swf-access-restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Only way I know of doing this is getting a SharedObject Reader (.sol file reader)

And editting this file

> C:\Documents and Settings{USERNAME}\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys\settings.sol

I'll be listed under `trustedPaths`

This automatically sets the trusted location settings.